# ScrollView is ignoring setScrollX()at high scrolling speeds

Tags: android, scrollview

So, I was going to create a custom view in order to get a photo album like tinder, a scrollview with autoadjust at photos positions. I thought an horizontalscrollview with a couple of tweaks would do the job. Added a 5*LayoutWidth horizontal LinerLayout to the scrollView sw and defined its onTouchListener like this:

```
sw.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            Log.d("MotionEvent", String.valueOf( event.getAction()));
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL){
                int scrollX=sw.getScrollX();
                Log.d("scrollX", String.valueOf( scrollX));
                //Log.d("layoutWidth", String.valueOf( layoutWidth));
                int aux = Math.round((float)scrollX/layoutWidth)*layoutWidth;
                Log.d("correction", String.valueOf( aux));
                sw.setScrollX(aux );



            }



            return false;
        }


    });
```

It is working just as expected, focusing on one of the 5 photos when releasing the touch input , but when I scroll and relese by fast gestures the scrollview is just ignoring sw.setScrollX(aux) and keeps scrolling. Can I do something to avoid this automatic scroll after release¿ Can I somehow manipulate the data of the input event¿

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. I extended the HorizontalcrollView like that:

```
public class stepScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {
public stepScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public stepScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public stepScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            Display d = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            d.getSize(size);
            int layoutWidth = size.x;
            int aux = Math.round((float)this.getScrollX()/layoutWidth)*layoutWidth;
            this.setScrollX(aux );


            return false; 
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}



}
```

it works with all the images you want to put in a Horizontal LinearLayout inner this custom view. You also have to resize your images to the stepScrollView horizontal dimension. In my case layoutWidth.